# Custom PHP Unit test trait for a custom module cannot be found

Tags: 8, testing

I have created a new Trait for testing my custom module and placed it in `my_module/tests/src/Traits` with the namespace `Drupal\Test\my_module\Traits`, the same as core modules do.

When I try to use this in my PHP Unit kernel test I just get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Trait 'Drupal\Test\my_module\Traits\CustomTrait' not found
```

Is there something special that needs to be included to allow custom traits in testing?

Answer (score 2):

The namespace should Drupal\Test**s**\my_module\Traits - notice this is Tests with an s at the end, not Test